# Preventing the same visitor from answering a poll more than once in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a polling website using Flask, and the issue is that I need to block users trying to vote more than once in a poll. I want the process to be simple, so I don't want to force users to login to vote. It should be something simple and straightforward. The solution should also be very scalable, so for instance, I'm not sure if storing the IP address of every visitor for every poll on the platform is a viable solution. Thanks.

More about the project:
There will be a two option poll, and users can access these polls through it's "username". So there will be a poll at `myurl.com/pollHere`, for instance. I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy to track the total votes for each poll.

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#sessions

Comment: Both sessions and storing user IPs can be tricked quite easily by clearing your cookies or changing your ip / using vpn etc. If that's not critical sessions would probably be the best thing.

Comment: Great thanks! My biggest worry is just people spamming a lot and creating bots to vote hundreds of times. Would that be a problem by using sessions?

Comment: Just don't use flask default session as it can be decoded easily, use flask-session
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-secure-is-the-flask-user-session

Comment: For me that would not be a problem because the only information I'm storing is a boolean that says whether or not a visitor has already voted, so it is not sensible information @ShivaGaire

Comment: Users can edit the session information; Users can alter the boolean value as the flask session is not secure enough.